# How to fix "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType" when packaging py2app

Tags: python, macos, compiler-errors, py2app

I am making a simple application that counts how many times an application (Minecraft) has been opened. I know that my way of approaching this problem is pretty rudimentry in behavior but I would appreciate any and all help that I may get.

When trying to package the script using py2app, the build unexpected failed giving me this error code

```
File "<frozen posixpath>", line 415, in realpath
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Here is my python script:

```
import os, getpass

path = "/Applications/Minecraft.app"
os.system(f"open {path}")
username = getpass.getuser()
with open ('/Users/'+username+'/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks/Splash/assets/minecraft/log.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("lol\n")


    with open ('/Users/'+username+'/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks/Splash/assets/minecraft/log.txt', 'r') as f:
        x = len(f.readlines())

    with open ('/Users/'+username+'/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks/Splash/assets/minecraft/texts/splashes.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("Opened " + str(x) + " times!")
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['minecraft.py']
DATA_FILES = ["icon.icns"]
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'icon.icns',
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'plist': {
        'LSUIElement': True,
    },
    'packages': ['os', 'getpass'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The terminal prompt I used:

`python3 setup.py py2app`

Also, I am using maccos ventura

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I'm pretty sure this is a simple issue with the os module but I haven't found a way to fix it after a few hours of struggle especially since the python script itself works fine when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this same issue for myself, if anyone else runs into it:
'os' should not be in your packages. (In your case getpass might also need to be removed and handled in your script instead)